# jQuery form ajaxSubmit not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I got a weird problem with ajaxSubmitting a form. My function gets triggered, but the ajaxSubmit itself does not get triggered.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='respond_4'></div>
<form method='post' id='cropper_4_infoForm' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='imag_title' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_filename' id='image_4_filename' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_x' id='image_4_x' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_y' id='image_4_y' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_width' id='image_4_width' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_height' id='image_4_height' />
    <input type='hidden' name='image_rotate' id='image_4_rotate' />
</form>

<button type='button' class='btn' onclick='SaveCropImageInfo();'><div class='icon icon-save'></div> Opslaan</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function SaveCropImageInfo() {
        console.log('going');
        $('#cropper_4_infoForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
            target:     '#respond_4', 
            url:        '/cms/modules/website/include/ajax/saveCropImageInfo.php?imag_id=4'
        });
    }
```

I have another form on this page that works on the same principal, but with different target and different url, but that form does work as intended. Hope one of you guys can help me out. :)

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmxpwt74/) to test and the `ajaxSubmit()` works properly there. Are you sure the problem is with your JavaScript and not with your PHP code?

Comment: how do you know the form gets submitted? the php code is just a simple die("ok") to check if the submit spits out a response to the target div. Nothing to go wrong there...

Comment: Open the JSFiddle link in either Firefox or Chrome. Press F12 to open the developer tools and click on the network tab. When you click the submit button you should see the request appear.